# automatically increment array dimension

Tags: php

I am trying to find a way to create an array of directories. But as we all know directories can have many subDirs and those subDirs can have more subDir and so on and on. **The directories length are unknown as it can change**.

Say I have a directory as `www/webs/apps/pics` and another `www/webs/test`.

The idea would be to have an array such as: (yes the below is json, i just converted it in my php demonstration because i find it easier to read)

```
{
  "www": {
     "webs": {
         "apps": {
            "pics": "Im Here"
             }
         },
       "test": "im Here too"
     }
}
```

There is no relation from the above output to the below code. The below code is here just to give an idea what I need.

```php
$exploedDir = explode("/", $unsortedDir);
foreach ($exploedDir as $dir){
    $this->allDirectiroesFound[$dir] = $dir;
}
```

How can I make `$this->allDirectiroesFound` has as many dimensions as it is needed without knowing the length of the directory, I cant hard code `$this->allDirectiroesFound[][][][][][]` it as next time around the array length might be `[][][]`.

Comment: Usually once you start to want more than "just arrays", it's time to pick a better datastructure. In this case, what you really want is a tree, not "an array of arrays of arrays of arrays of ..."

Comment: I think the question I linked should handle this perfectly for you. Here's a working example with your example paths: https://3v4l.org/PEBrL

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks

Comment: @Don'tPanic could explain the pass by reference bit? why does the second ```foreach``` loop needs this temp as pass by reference ```&$temp[$key];```? thanks

Comment: Normally PHP will pass everything by value. If you assign `$temp = $temp[$key];` without the reference, then `$temp` just takes the _value_ of `$temp[$key]`, which is `null` because it hasn't been set to any value yet. With the reference assignment, `$temp` points to `$temp[$key]` instead of taking its value so you're able to continue to add nested keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just reverse each of the path arrays and then go on creating the Keys from the last directory.

```
$paths = [
    'www/webs/apps/pics',
    'www/webs/test',
];

$finalArray = [];
foreach($paths as $path){
    $revArr = array_reverse(explode("/", $path)); // This is the trick. Start to build from inside out.
    $pathArray = [];
    foreach($revArr as $key){
            $tempBucket = $pathArray;
            $pathArray = []; // Create fresh empty array to hold the 
            $pathArray[$key] = $tempBucket;
    }

    $finalArray = array_merge_recursive($pathArray, $finalArray); // Recursively Merge the array into the main array
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_encode($finalArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
echo "</pre>";
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/FvB2Wi)

Comment: Thanks this is a good way of doing I never used ```array_reverse``` before so its something nice to learn :)

Comment: Indeed it is, then there are more optimal solutions as suggested by the community which this questions is a duplicate of. I just wrote this code off the top of my head in 5 mins :) I myself learned a new thing in this endeavour, viz. Accessing a non existent array key **by reference** will create it!! Like Wow!!! I guess, everyone's learning new things here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would need to use arrays of arrays to solve this.

e.g.

```
var directories = ["base"];
var subdir1 = ["subdir1"];
var subsubdir1 = ["subsubdir1"];
var subsubdir1 = ["subsubdir2"];

subdir.push(subsubdir1);
subdir.push(subsubdir2);
directories.push(subdir1);
```

so this forms a base->subdir1->[subsubdir1, subsubdir2] structure. The complication comes in ensuring that every 'push' you perform is an array to allow adjacent siblings to exist for that particular sub-directory. That and keeping track of the directory structure